# Customising android layout similar to skype notification icon

Tags: android

I want to create android notification icon  as shown in the messaging icon.The layout above the icon is displaying the number of inbox message. I want similar layout.

[image]

I tried with nested layout but unable to success.

Is there any possible links.

Answer (score 1):

afaik, doing this on android is not possible without using a widget or modifying the rom.
It looks like the screenshot you have there is a version of TouchWiz: that's what samsung did, and it only works for their native apps.

You can definitely do it using widgets, but the obvious limitation is that it the widget has to be placed on the home screen first. The badge will not show on the app launcher.

Edit:

If you just want to badge your views with a number similar to the one shown above, you can use this library called viewbadger: https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-viewbadger

Comment: I have seen this done in many apps where they design close button (x) similar to the above image.Is it not possible through nested layout?

Comment: you're probably talking about a different Launcher. No, I don't think it's possible.

Comment: I think you are talking about icon launcher. But the matter is about layout design in xml.